# how to define an acceptable range of values using jquery mask plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mask, masking

How to define an acceptable range of values (0-9999)?

if mask is defined as

```
.mask('9999')
```

acceptable values will be in range from 1000 to 9999 but I need values between 0 and 9999

Comment: Can you post a link to the plugin?

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
.mask('9?999')
```

From http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

> You can have part of your mask be optional. Anything listed after '?' within the mask is considered optional user input.

Comment: thank you kind sirs, I'll accept an answer I suppose it was posted first

Answer (score 1):

After `?` makes it optional:

```
.mask('9?999')
```